# Solana Wallet adapter with different react UI

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, typescript, react-native

I am a newbie to React/Typescript and I am trying to build a DeFi project using the Solana Wallet adapter. From what I can see the wallet adapter comes with a React UI look and feel based on the Solana colour scheme.

I want to use a different colour scheme for my project. Is there a way to override the default colour scheme in the wallet adapter code? At present, I removed the UI imports i.e.

```
import {
    WalletModalProvider,
    WalletDisconnectButton,
    WalletMultiButton
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
```

and the wallet button looks like this:

[image: wallet button without wallet-adapter-react-ui]

It doesn't look particularly good or professional. I am trying to do a POC for a presentation. I feel like I would need to invest a lot of time to customise it manually. I don't have that time, plus I could do all that work and then find out there was an easier approach.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wallet adapter styles can be added  like so

`require("@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css");`

You can also find the class naming convention and override the css.

Comment: Thank so much. I copied over the CSS file into my project and changed the colours there and it worked perfectly. Thanks again.